# What is the equivalent of die() in Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-4

In `PHP` there is the `die("some message");` to write output and stop the execution of the script. So is there an equivalent in `Spring mvc` ( in `Controller` and in the `JSP` ) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to have something like die() in Java/JSPs. JSPs should be used as a pure view technology. It should just generate HTML. Not try to access a database, read files or whatnot. That is the job of a controller, written in Java

Use `System.exit(0);` to exit the java code.

Keep a note this will stop the JVM instance which is currently running.

If you want to come out of a method use return or throw exception to showcase error condition.