# What is similar function of dd() from Laravel in Spring?

Tags: spring, laravel

I recently change to Spring-boot for development. Can anyone help me to understand better in Spring?

In laravel, there is `dd()` function, which is useful to dump variable value. The picture below show the result of `dd()`. Can I achieve same thing in Spring?

[image: Result of 'dd()']

Comment: Why not use `system.exit(0)`

Comment: `dd()` translates to `dump and die`. [JSP die() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158903/6463262)

Comment: `system.exit()` in my understanding only terminates JVM but it does not display the data of a variable. I edited my question with an example.

Comment: hope it can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158903/6850994

Comment: you can also use `dump()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such behavior, but you can make it similar.

1. Create an exception and include the result data you want to see.
2. Register the exception in the `@ExceptionHandler`.
3. If you want to be global, create an `@ExceptionHandler` in `@ControllerAdvice`.